# ISAPI Redirect 3 Filter 301 Redirect with subdomain

Tags: regex, redirect, url-rewriting, iis-6, isapi

I'm very new in terms of writing rules for ISAPI Rewrite 3 from Helicon (licensed version) to be used for IIS6.  I need to write 90+ rules for different pages from "subdomain.domain.com" to "www.domain.com", and I'm not very familiar with RegEx patterns.  Unfortunately, these sites don't mirror, so doing a simple query string append won't work.

Example: Redirect "http://subdomain.domain.com/products/product.aspx?id=42" to "http://www.domain.com/productgroup/productinfo"

I have a pretty good start on it, however the furthest I've gotten is to get a specific page redirect to work.  I need to get it down to the specific ID for some of these pages to redirect differently.  Currently, the code I have for the web page redirect to Google (just for testing purposes) is

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.102

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(subfolder.html)/?(.*)$ http://www.google.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

NOTE: I just created a simple website with the following pages:
 - /index.html
 - /subfolder/subfolder.html
 - /subfolder/subfolder2.html
 - /subdir/subdir.html

According to the previous code, "/subfolder/subfolder.html" redirects to Google and the others show the page normally.  For testing purposes, I've been trying to append "id=1" to redirect to YouTube and "id=2" to redirect to Facebook, and neither of those are working at the moment.  The code for that is

```
RewriteRule ^(subfolder2.html\?id=1)$ http://www.youtube.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(subfolder2.html\?id=2)$ http://www.facebook.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

All I need is to get a pattern that works, then I can modify it from there to make it work for the rest of the pages.

Thank you for any responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, this is how I ended up getting it to work.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule products/product_detail.aspx http://www.newdomain.com/NewProductPage [NC,R=301,L]
```

From my understanding of it the "RewriteCond" looks for that ID (in this case).  The RewriteRule consists of the original URL **without** the query string (products/product_detail.aspx) and the redirected URL (http://www.newdomain.com/NewProductPage).